# Combining multiple try-catch blocks into one

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, code-cleanup

Here is a sample block of code

```
// rebuild session state for test, need the current phase first
String phaseName = testtaker.getPhase();
TestPhase phase = null;

try {
    phase = objFactory.getPhase(testtaker.getTestengine(), phaseName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception when getting phase for testtaker.", e);
    CaslsUtils.outputLoggingData(log_, request);
    // Toss the exception back to the engine, add a message
    throw new Exception("Cannot create phase: " + phaseName);
}

try {
    // Adding this code to improve the performance of the application during student login
    Testtaker newTestTaker = objFactory.getDataAccessor().getTesttakerByTestTakerId(testtaker.getTesttakerid());// This will populate testtaker object with all its child table records
    if(newTestTaker != null) {
        session.setAttribute(ConstantLibrary.SESSION_TESTTAKER, newTestTaker);
    }
    phase.rebuildTest(session);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception when calling rebuildTest.", e);
    CaslsUtils.outputLoggingData(log_, request);
    // Toss the exception back to the engine, add a message
    throw new Exception("Cannot Rebuild Test");
}
```

Kindly help me how to combine this code in a multi-catch statement as when I try to do it, it generates error in second catch block as unreachable code.

Comment: You can't catch the exact same exception in two `catch` blocks. Also, don't catch `Exception`.

Comment: `catch(ThisException | ThatException | OhMyGodException e)`

Comment: Please show us what you attempted.

Comment: @MarounMaroun is right, but it only works in Java 7+. For Java <= 6, there is no multi-catch option at all.